# Circuit breaker and capacitance

Tags: electric-circuits, voltage, capacitance

I have a problem with knowing witch capacitor to use in a circuit because I am working on installing main circuit breaker where it is needed for 220 Volt AC current to be turned in to a lower current of 12 Volt useing a tramsformer. I would like to know how to calculate the capacity in farads without knowing the charge of the capacitor needed. The formula to calculate the capacitance of a capacitor Q=C/V would be more usefull in my opinion if I could know how to determine the charge of a capacitor.I want the AC current to be turned into DC current useing the right capacitor

Comment: You can't turn AC into DC using just a capacitor.

Comment: This question is probably more suitable for the Electrical Engineering site than Physics. But please take a look at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/73863 first, so that you don't ask a duplicate question there.

Comment: I suppose you have a rectifier and  want to know what capacitor goes behind it? It very much depends from the amount of current you will be using on the 12V= side, the larger the current, the larger the capacitor,

Answer (score 0):

To convert AC to DC, you will need a pn-junction (atleast two) which will allow for full-wave rectification of the current. This can be stabilized with the help of a capacitor in parallel or an inductor in series. The exact calculations depend on the specifications of the circuit.